# How open a URL in another tab when click on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My modal display an intern URL with iFrame. I'm looking to open this intern URL when you click inside the modal.

My code bellow doesn't work. When I click inside the modal nothing happening. The code works only when I click on the close button.

Thanks for help

See the code updated with your answer. It still doesn't work. My close button doesn't work anymore

```js
$('#cosmeto').click(function() {
  $('#cosmetomodal').show().addClass('modal-open');
});

$('#closec').click(function() {
  var elem = $('#cosmetomodal');
  elem.removeClass('modal-open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.hide();
  },200);
});

$('#myiframe').on('click', function(){
  elem.removeClass('modal-open');
  elem.hide();
  window.open('google.fr','');
});
```

```css
.cosmetomodal {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index:9999;

    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */

    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
}

.cosmeto-content {
  position:fixed;
  width:60%;
  top:55%;
  left:50%;
  padding:15px;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  opacity:0;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);  
  transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: scroll;
  text-align: center;
}

.cosmetomodal.modal-open #cosmeto-content {
  opacity:1;
  top:50%;
}

#myiframe {
  position: fixed;
  left:0;
  z-index: 999;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
    <div id="cosmetomodal" class="cosmetomodal" style="display:none;">
       <div id="cosmeto-content" class="cosmeto-content">
        <div id="myiframe"></div>
          <iframe src="principes_actifs.html" onload="iframeResize(this);" style="border:none;" ></iframe>
          <button id="closec" type="button">Close </button>
     </div>
    </div>   

    <div id="file" class ="container">
     <input id="vegetal" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/vegetal.png" height="250px" width="250px" />
    </div>
```

Comment: i think you just need to add `target="_blank"` to your <a> tag

Comment: I already did it but still nothing :-/

Comment: If you leave an upvote and remember to valide the answer i tell you how to do it.

Comment: I am pretty sure wrapping in an anchor tag around and iframe is bad syntax.  An anchor tag is an inline element, whereas an iframe is a block element.   Inline elements should not contain block elements.

Comment: Can you try adding a `base` tag with `target="_blank"` inside your head element as shown in [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_base_test)?

Comment: Also, list @eat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place an invisible div `<div class="myiframe"></div>` that covers the area of the popup being set to absolute, and use javascript to say when it's clicked go to url. Have to set the correct z-indexes with css.

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e351ck0d/1/

Remove `,'_blank'` from `window.open('https://google.com','_blank');` and write instead `,'_self'` if want to open the url in the same window.

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="file" class ="container">
                    <input id="cosmeto" type="image" src="IMAGES/PNG/principes_actifs.png" height="250px" width="250px"/>
                </div>
                <div id="cosmetomodal" class="cosmetomodal" style="display:none;">
                    <div id="cosmeto-content" class="cosmeto-content">
              <div class="myiframe"></div>
                            <iframe  src="principes_actifs.html" onload="iframeResize(this);"></iframe>
                            <button id="closec" type="button">Close </button>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cosmetomodal {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index:9999;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
}

.cosmeto-content {
  position:fixed;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
  width:70%;
  left:50%;
  padding:15px;
  background-color:#fafafa;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  opacity:0;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);  
  transition:all 300ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cosmetomodal.modal-open #cosmeto-content {
  opacity:1;
  top:50%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.myiframe {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  z-index: 2;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#closec {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

JS:

```
var elem = $('#cosmetomodal');
$('#cosmeto').click(function() {
  $('#cosmetomodal').show().addClass('modal-open');
});

$('.myiframe').on('click', function(){
  elem.removeClass('modal-open');
  elem.hide();
  window.open('https://google.com','_blank');
});

$('#closec').click(function() {
  elem.removeClass('modal-open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.hide();
  },200);
});
```

**EDIT:** to fix the scroll bar, you can set the absolute overlay div to start 30px (or use %) from right, like this:

```
.myiframe {
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  z-index: 2;
  top:0;
  right:30px;
  bottom:0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

and the iframe to occupy the whole modal width:

```
.cosmeto-content iframe {
  width: 100%;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** a slightly different approach, while i start to understand what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/e351ck0d/2/

I've set the iframe to show in its entire height, but a fixed height to the popup, so you'll only scroll the popup, keeping both the invisible div with link and scroll functionality). Also i had to place the button outside (check the html part too.

Comment: It doesn't work :-/ I added the CSS code, the html Code and the Javascript. When I click on the iFrame nothing happening and my close button doesn't work anymore

Comment: It does it does, i update it with the working jsfiddle now

Comment: with or without _blank in the javascript file it's the same :-/

Comment: Edited, you have to use '_self' instead of '_blank' if want to open the url in the same window.

Comment: I also updated it with the correct css for the button, it's positioned with absolute now and works

Comment: Theres a mistake yes, place the   var elem = $('#cosmetomodal');   outside of any function, at the top as i did.

Comment: that's perfect !! Just my close button moved from the center do you know why ?

Comment: I just see another "bug". I can't scroll anymore in my iframe modal :'(

Comment: You're right cause the div is overlaying it, let it start from a certain amount of px (or %) from right and the scroll bar is usable. I edited with an example.

Comment: I found a slightly different solution, let me know what you think: http://jsfiddle.net/e351ck0d/2/  (i've set the iframe to show in its entire height, but a fixed height to the popup, so you'll only scroll the popup, keeping both the invisible div with link and scroll functionality). Also i had to place the button outside (check the html part too).

Comment: Thx, I'll check tomorrow. It's late here and low battery on my top. Thx you very much for your help ! See you tomorrow ☺️

Comment: it does the job ! Can you explain me what you did ?

Comment: Since the popup is seen as a "view" i used height: 100vh (view height) on the iframe, and let only the popup to scroll (wasn't good anyway to have both the popup and the iframe with a scroll-bar), so this way since the overlaying invisible div covers the iframe, not the popup, the iframe is clickable while you can scroll down (the popup) at the same time.